# Homotopy equivalence of spaces involving spheres and projective space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Let $Y = S^2 \times \mathbb{R} P^3$ and $X =  S^3 \times \mathbb{R} P^2$. Let $y \in Y$ and $x \in X $ be basepoints.

$(a) $ Compute $\pi_{1}(Y,y) $ and $\pi_{1}(X,x)$.

$(b)$ Show that $\pi_{k}(Y,y) = \pi_{k}(X,x)$ for all integers $k \geq 1$

$(c)$ Are these spaces homotopy equivalent?

I know that the fundamental group of $S^2$ is $0$. But,

- how do I compute the fundamental group of it's product with $\mathbb{R} P^3$? Do I have to use the Van Kampen theorem? I'm also confused about how to compute $\pi_{1}(X,x)$.
- For part$(c)$, my intuition is that they are indeed homotopic but I'm not sure how to show that explicitly.
- I don't know where to start with part$(b)$ either.

Comment: The fundamental group preserves products - that is, $\pi_1(A \times B, (a, b)) \simeq \pi_1(A, a) \times \pi_1(B, b)$.

Comment: For (b), consider their universal covers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a), Mark Saving's comment gives that $\pi_1(S^3\times \mathbb{R}P^2)\cong\pi_1(\Bbb RP^2)\cong\pi_1(\Bbb RP^3)\cong\pi_1(S^2\times \Bbb RP^3)$, so they are isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2$.

For b), we already showed that their fundamental groups are isomorphic in a), and we know that the universal covering $p:E\to B$ induces isomorphism on $p_\ast:\pi_n(E)\to\pi_n(B)$ for all $n\ge 2$, so let's construct their universal cover. Suppose $p_1:S^2\to S^2$ and $p_2:S^3\to\Bbb RP^3$ are two covering maps, then $p_1\times p_2$ gives the desired universal cover of $S^2\times \Bbb RP^3$. Similarly, $S^2\times S^3$ is also the universal cover of $S^3\times \Bbb RP^2$. They admit the same universal cover, and so their higher homotopy groups are isomorphic.

For c), yours is a good guess, but unfortunately it is not the case. These two spaces are not homotopy equivalent despite their isomorphic homotopy groups in all dimensions. You can deduce it by computing the top homology group using Künneth formula, which gives us
\begin{align}
H_5(S^2\times \Bbb RP^3;\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z\\
H_5(S^3\times \Bbb RP^2;\Bbb Z)\cong0
\end{align}

Comment: Orientability is a topological invariant but not an homotopy invariant (consider $\Bbb S^1$ and the Möbius band) I think that you cannot deduce $(c)$ form the fact that $Y$ is orientable and $X$ it isn’t. On the contrary homology groups are homotopy invariants so the alternative proof works well:)

Comment: Well, for closed manifolds, orientability *is* a homotopy invaraint, since it is detected by the top cohomology group.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes. I was just about to say that, but I need to quote the theorem before claiming that orientability issue implies non-homotopy equivalence (which means there was indeed some problem with my arugment). I decided to delete that paragraph because it's essentially the same as the argument of top (co)homology group.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: are these spaces weakly homotopy equivalent?

Comment: @Brain no they are not. Because Whitehead theorem states that for two CW complexes, weak homotopy equivalence implies homotopy equivalence.